# Rigging a curve non destructively

Tags: modifiers, rigging, bezier-curves

I'm using a curve with the curve modifier and array modifier to make a hose.  However, I want to be able to animate the hose easily without keyframing all the parts of the curve. I've heard people here say you can rig an object by converting the curve to a mesh but then my curve modifier wouldn't work if I tried that. Basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to animate something like my hose with modifiers **not** applied, in a simple way.  Hopefully this make sense.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use hooks to points and curve handles. Then you can parent the hooks to a rig or bone

Comment: Armature in Pose Mode. You can add a Spline IK Constraint.  Your question would be clearer with some screen captures.

Comment: Sorry for the late response...I've been trying understand rigging lol.  Are there any good beginner tutorials on how to do what you guys are describing?